# How can i optimize the energy consumption in MAC Protocols for Wireless Sensor Networks

Tags: omnet++

i'am beginner in omnet++ and i have installed inet to simulate the energy consumption of wireless sensor network. So please help me.

```
# radio and radioMedium
**.radio.centerFrequency = 2.45GHz
**.radio.bandwidth = 2.8MHz

**.radio.transmitter.bitrate = 19200 bps
**.radio.transmitter.headerLength = 8b
**.radio.transmitter.preambleDuration = 0.0001s
**.radio.transmitter.power = 2.24mW

**.radio.receiver.energyDetection = -90dBm
**.radio.receiver.sensitivity = -100dBm
**.radio.receiver.snirThreshold = -8dB

*.radioMedium.backgroundNoise.power = -110dBm

**.mac.headerLength = 8b`
```

**and this is the configuration of mac protocoles**

```
[Config StatisticBMac]
extends = StatisticBase

**.wlan[*].mac.typename = "BMac"
**.wlan[*].mac.headerLength = 1B
**.wlan[*].mac.slotDuration = ${slotDuration=0.01..1 step 0.01}s

[Config StatisticXMac]
extends = StatisticBase

**.wlan[*].mac.typename = "XMac"
**.wlan[*].mac.headerLength = 24B
*.gateway.wlan[*].mac.slotDuration = ${gwSlotDuration=0.01..1 step 0.01}s
*.sensor*.wlan[*].mac.slotDuration = ${snSlotDuration=2.5*$gwSlotDuration}s

[Config StatisticLMac]
extends = StatisticBase

**.wlan[*].mac.typename = "LMac"
**.mac.slotDuration = ${slotDuration=0.01..1 step 0.01}s
**.mac.numSlots = 8
**.mac.reservedMobileSlots = 0
```